# Why does only one of the DC circuit power equations work for me here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

[image]

I know that $$ P=IV=I^2R=\frac{V^2}{R}$$

I solved for the current using the loop rule $$I=.47$$ but to solve for the Power output of the 16V battery I could only find the power by finding the terminal voltage of the battery and using $$P=IV$$ the other two gave me incorrect answers and I'm just lost shouldn't I be able to use whichever I want?

Comment: Please provide the calculations that are giving you the correct and incorrect values.

Comment: Don't do this to batteries. Who would write a problem like that?

Answer (score 0):

When you solve the loop current $I$, you need the total resistance $R_{tot}$ and total voltage $V_{tot}$ to compute $I = V/R$. The total voltage is obtain by the difference between the two batteries because they **compete with one another**, so this is reflected in the current, which is lower than it would if it was a single battery. I guess to look at the single battery's output you need to take it's voltage $V_1$ and the total resistance $R_{tot}$.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal pd is $V=\mathcal E -IR$ where the emf of the battery is $\mathcal E, \,I$ is the current and $R$ is the internal resistance.
So the power delivered to the outside circuit is $VI=\mathcal E \,I-I^2R$

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the battery itself as you represent it in your diagram does not have a resistance. It has an internal resistance $R=16~\Omega$ for which the formula $P=RI^2$ can be used but the voltage $16~V$ is pure potential such that the only valid formula is $P=VI$.

Consequently, the battery releases a power $P_V=I*16=7.52~W$ and its internal resistance dissipates $P_{R}=1.6I^2=0.35~W$. For the internal resistance all 3 expression of power should work because its a resistance.

The net output power released by the battery to the rest of the circuit can then be considered $P=P_v-P_{R}=7.52-0.35=7.71~W$.

Although I do not see the point of putting a battery $8V$ opposite to the first battery..

Answer (score 0):

The relation

$$P=IV$$

is a general relation for any kind of circuit element.

The other two versions

$$P=\frac{V^2}{R}$$
and
$$P=I^2R$$

are special case formulas that apply to resistors. They are derived by substituting Ohm's law into the general relationship.

Since a battery is not a resistor, you can't expect either of the formulas for a resistor to apply to it.

Similarly, you can't expect to use Ohm's law to find the voltage given the current or current given the voltage for the battery.